# PHP 8.2 FPM Deprecation Warnings

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

So, I recently switched to PHP8.2 fpm for a server running WordPress. It seems like there are some support issues for this. I am considering downgrading. However, this has caused an immediate problem: my errors.log is filling up (about 70GB per day) with deprecation warnings.

As a stopgap, I've implemented a cron job to empty the logs every 10 minutes.

Things I have tried:

1. I have edited the `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini` to remove deprecation warnings like so:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

I then restarted both nginx and php8.2-fpm. This DID NOT WORK.

2. I put some code into wp-config.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

This also DID NOT WORK.

3. I tried setting `log_errors = Off` this DOES WORK, however, now it doesn't log errors, which is not optimal.

I am basically at my wits end. I am currently writing a script to manually edit all of the files to add `#[\AllowDynamicProperties]` above every class definition as these are the bulk (not all) of the Deprecation errors.

I would really like to get rid of these deprecation warnings. But most likely, I'll have to downgrade to an earlier version of PHP. This website has so much custom code that there is no way to fix it all.

Did I do something wrong with the php.ini? Is there something special to make it work?

The specific problem is this: I have implemented the various recommendations from online,and they didn't work, so what did I do wrong? And how can I make it work?

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you running?

Comment: Did you reboot the server after changing it's config? Are you sure, the correct config was edited? Look via phpinfo() from the wp-config.php. Maybe the logs are written from a cli process and not via fpm?

Comment: You could downgrade, then make your changes gradually in a development environment which is on the higher version, and then deploy it to live in your own time, when you're ready.

Comment: Personally, I'd downgrade. We host many websites and we're still not recommending 8.2. We know of at least one very popular plugin with 700,000+ installs that only mentions PHP 8.1 support still. We do have sites running 8.2, we're just not recommending it until we get better support from the community as a whole.

Comment: To your problem, you should know that WordPress [stomps the PHP error reporting level](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/bbe60d66c32c9a0b401b15e32fa28db958509c65/wp-includes/load.php#L481), although deprecations should not be logged when not in debug. One way around this is to create an mu-plugin that resets the logging levels back to where you want them. You might want to grep your site to see if anyone else is calling `error_reporting`. You might be able to run a tool such as Rector or PHP Stan against your codebase to find and potentially correct these issues.

Comment: I am currently using the latest wordpress, and will likely try to downgrade the php, as too many things are broken for no good reason. 

I did restart the server (software) not the actual virtual machine.

I did find an unhelpful fix, in the php.ini file, I turned off error logging entirely. However, now I can't find errors so that doesn't work.